# Function not invoking decorator

Tags: python, discord.py

I've been trying to setup slash commands in my Discord bot, and for one of them I need to check if the user is either the owner of the server or has "Admins" or "Mods" roles.

It was simply done before (while using commands.command) by defining function below:

```py
def mods_or_owner():
    def predicate(ctx):
        return commands.check_any(commands.is_owner(), commands.has_role(MODERATOR_ROLE_NAME))

    return commands.check(predicate)
```

And then calling it when defining the function to use the decorator:

```py
...
@commands.command()
@mods_or_owner()
async def foo(self, ctx):
    await ctx.send("bar")
```

But after implementing the `app_commands` for the slash commands, I haven't been able to invoke the decorator properly. It goes right through it and enables the command to any user in the server.

The new definition of decorator function is as below:

```py
def mods_or_owner():
    def predicate(interaction: discord.Interaction):
        return discord.app_commands.checks.has_any_role(commands.is_owner(), MODERATOR_ROLE_NAME)
    check = app_commands.check(predicate)
    # DEBUG
    # print(check)
    return check
```

And the invoking part is as below:

```py
@app_commands.command(name='foo', description="")
@mods_or_owner()
    async def status(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, member: discord.Member = None)
    ...
    await interaction.response.send_message("bar")
```

The decorator is never invoked. I've already tried to change order of decorators, but issue persists.

Comment: That's a suspicious looking decorator -- it returns `None` rather than a function...and since it doesn't take an argument, it should fail with a `TypeError` exception when you try to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per discord.py support, this is not commonly done nor recommended.

- "You generally should not be doing local checks in slash commands. This is a use case for the integrations ui to limit to roles. The server owner, the server admins can setup the command permissions themselves."